# How to write for loop or episode in Pyspark

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, and I am trying to write a for loop on it.

```
|ID   | from_dt  | To_dt    |row_number|diff|negetive_or_not|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+
|11111|2020-07-30|2020-07-31|         1|  -2|              0|
|11111|2020-08-02|2020-08-11|         2|   4|              1|
|11111|2020-08-07|2020-08-08|         3|  -4|              0|
|11111|2020-08-12|2020-08-18|         4|   1|              1|
|11111|2020-08-17|2020-08-19|         5|   0|              1|
|11111|2020-08-19|2020-08-22|         6|   2|              1|
|11111|2020-08-20|2020-08-24|         7|  -1|              0|
|11111|2020-08-25|2020-08-27|         8|   0|              1|
|11111|2020-08-27|2020-08-31|         9|-999|              0|
```

The goal is to determine the episode.  if the negative or not start with 0, it is an episode, if the negative or not start with 1, until it hit 0, it is an episode.

Here is the ideal output

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+
|ID   | from_dt  | To_dt    |row_number|diff|negetive_or_not| Episode
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+
|11111|2020-07-30|2020-07-31|         1|  -2|              0|   1
|11111|2020-08-02|2020-08-11|         2|   4|              1|   2
|11111|2020-08-07|2020-08-08|         3|  -4|              0|   2
|11111|2020-08-12|2020-08-18|         4|   1|              1|   3 
|11111|2020-08-17|2020-08-19|         5|   0|              1|   3 
|11111|2020-08-19|2020-08-22|         6|   2|              1|   3 
|11111|2020-08-20|2020-08-24|         7|  -1|              0|   3 
|11111|2020-08-25|2020-08-27|         8|   0|              1|   4
|11111|2020-08-27|2020-08-31|         9|-999|              0|   4
|22222|2020-07-30|2020-07-31|         1|  -2|              0|   1
|22222|2020-08-02|2020-08-11|         2|   4|              1|   2
|22222|2020-08-07|2020-08-08|         3|  -4|              0|   2
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+
```

I tried to use case when and rank, such as

case when negetive_or_not = 0 then "eps1" else then "eps2", both not working.

```
df2 = df.selectExpr('*') .withColumn("Episode",lead(col("to_dt")).over(Window.partitionBy("patient_id").orderBy(col("negetive_or_not"))))
```

I also try to write a for loop in pyspark, but I have difficulty transferring dataframe into the list, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach goes as

1. First flag the row when the value should change.
2. Based on the flag generate a new value.
3. Forward fill the nulls

```
df.withColumn('flag', when(((col('negetive_or_not')==1) & (lag('negetive_or_not').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('row_number'))==0)) | (lag('negetive_or_not').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('row_number')).isNull()), lit('change')).otherwise(lit('no'))).\
   withColumn('ep', when(col('flag')=='change',row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('ID','flag').orderBy('row_number')))).\
   withColumn('Episode', last('ep', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('row_number'))).\
   drop('flag','ep').show()

+-----+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+-------+
|   ID|   from_dt|     To_dt|row_number|diff|negetive_or_not|Episode|
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+-------+
|11111|2020-07-30|2020-07-31|         1|  -2|              0|      1|
|11111|2020-08-02|2020-08-11|         2|   4|              1|      2|
|11111|2020-08-07|2020-08-08|         3|  -4|              0|      2|
|11111|2020-08-12|2020-08-18|         4|   1|              1|      3|
|11111|2020-08-17|2020-08-19|         5|   0|              1|      3|
|11111|2020-08-19|2020-08-22|         6|   2|              1|      3|
|11111|2020-08-20|2020-08-24|         7|  -1|              0|      3|
|11111|2020-08-25|2020-08-27|         8|   0|              1|      4|
|11111|2020-08-27|2020-08-31|         9|-999|              0|      4|
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----+---------------+-------+
```